# 'Error: No such file or directory' when saving data to cloud kit

Tags: swift2, ios9, backend, cloudkit

I'm still relatively new to programming and i'm trying to create a record in the cloud kit backend programmatically, but I get an error no such file or directory method every time I run it in the iOS simulator or search for it on the CloudKit dashboard. Can anyone share how to properly save a record in swift 2?

Below is my latest miserable attempt:

```
@IBAction func saveRecord(sender: AnyObject) {            
        var record = CKRecord(recordType: "BTVRecord")
        record.setValue("title", forKey: "string")
        CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.saveRecord(record, completionHandler: 
                                        { (savedRecord: CKRecord!, error: NSError!) -> Void in})}
```

Comment: Also I omitted the code containing the successful or non successful completion of the message

Comment: On what moment do you get the error? If you set a breakpoint on the first line of the saveRecord function, then do you get the error before or after that breakpoint. Then on what line do you get the error? Could you show us the complete error message?

Comment: I was actually able to rectify it by changing the record to a constant and also I was also using an outdated version of swift so I found an example that was used for swift2